# Return different type by string in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given we have two different types as below, how can we change the return of function based on a string parameter and not providing the generic type?

```
interface Type1 { typeName: string; };
interface Type2 { typeVersion: string; };
type AllTypes = Type1 | Type2;

function returnTypes(t: string): AllTypes {
  ...
}

const typeResult = returnTypes('type1');
console.log(typeResult.typeName);
```

Here the return is not defined!

Answer (score 9):

Create an overloaded declaration like so

```
interface Type1 { typeName: string; };
interface Type2 { typeVersion: string; };
type AllTypes = Type1 | Type2;

function returnTypes(t: 'type1'): Type1;
function returnTypes(t: 'type2'): Type2;
function returnTypes(t : 'type1' | 'type2'): AllTypes {
    switch (t) {
        case "type1": return { typeName: "test" };
        case "type2": return { typeVersion: "test" };
    }
}

console.log(returnTypes('type1').typeName);
console.log(returnTypes('type2').typeVersion);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECMyDeyYWEAcnALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcyAvqwFCiSyIUGbACYCREgDVodYAHsQtBkxBtOPYtmQBBADa7hEOsgC8aEngA+50T24wAriARh5IZFAhgHUEIboAFGC0AOSauCEAlLSGODyOzq4KHl4+fiSBwchhJCJRMbnxTi5uKd6+-kHIoeE4IcjWOaL5Ovr+BNzIXfQA7sBgCAAWyEGRHd0TyAhwdCgARLVztJ7l7oTh5FS0C0Zgc+qdk13Ts8gLuUtlaeLh0lCyCtuQDPtch10c3J-cCAp0croIAA6XRyZgBFZpSpNCKRIEbSgQSI8X4gf6AkFgiGpCoZAIwvJw24yNzIoA)

Note that when you overload a function in this manner, the implementation signature is not available to callers. Only the declarations specified beforehand comprise an overloaded function's interface.

**UPDATE:** Fixed and completed example to show that TypeScript knows which type it is returning.

Comment: How do you turn `t` which is string to the returning type `Type` or `Type2`?

Comment: Rodrigo, thank you for the edit. It is now much clearer. @PRAISER I'm not sure I understand the question, could you rephrase it?

Comment: Is it possible to use your above syntax while using `const a = () => {}` format or does it have to be `function a () {}`?

Comment: @ArturTagisow It works if you take advantage of type inference. The compiler will recognize the correlation between the parameter and return types. However, if you want to write it out, or you're in an ambient context, you would need to use a union of function types and it gets ugly https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?downlevelIteration=true&target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUygVzmAKgTwA4IjAXhgAooAuGAcihwQEZKYAfKm3AJkoEpCA+GAN4BYAFAxxMCAHcAllGAALElB7CxEjcACGEBDABEbevoqIUaQTCMA5LQFsEFQ3ij6YAXwDcojRoAmCABmWsgANuQw2roGRuwm8EioYJZGAGoIcBAy4E5QLm5ePhLuou5AA

Comment: @AluanHaddad So as the method returnTypes returns only one type you have to rename `AllTypes`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template type 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

```
private returnTypes<T>(arg:T): T {
    return arg
}
```

Otherwise you'd have to set switch cases based on your arg

```
returnTypes(arg:string): AllTypes {
    switch(arg){
        case "type1": return SomethingOfType1
        case "type2": return SomethingOfType2
    }
}
```

A bit more information about what you're trying to accomplish might help.

Comment: This solution won't solve the problem, at the end once function return the result, it's returning which one is it `Type1` or `Type2`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have an array of objects with different types. All objects have the same field ID. My task is to extract one object by ID. And I want to make sure that object has specific type. I don't want to use question marks in my types.

Here is my solution -

```js
interface Object1 { 
    id: string;
    color: string; 
};

interface Object2 { 
    id: string;
    age: number; 
};

type ObjectType = Object1 | Object2;

function getObject(arr: any, id: '101'): Object1;

function getObject(arr: any, id: '102'): Object2;

function getObject(arr: any, id : '101' | '102'): ObjectType {
    return arr.find((item) => item.id === id);
}

const arr = [
    {
        id: '101',
        color: 'white',
    },
    {
        id: '102',
        age: 12,
    }
]

console.log(getObject(arr, '101').color);
console.log(getObject(arr, '102').age);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it *seems* like you are trying to define a function that returns one of several types.  So for example the function would return either Type1 or Type2.  Unless the two types share a common set of functionality,  you would then need to check the type before calling a potentially different method on the returned object.

Assuming the objects you are returning **do** share a common set of functionality, it would be better to define that in an interface and then declare that each object type you want to return implements that interface.

So as an example.

```
interface CommonStuff {
  someFunction();
  someOtherFunction();
}

class Type1 implements CommonStuff {
  someFunction() {}
  someOtherFunction() {}
}  

class Type2 implements CommonStuff {
  someFunction() {}
  someOtherFunction() {}
}
```

Then simply have your function return a type of CommonStuff

```
returnTypes(str:String) : CommonStuff {
   let x : Type1;
   let y : Type2;
   ...
   const z = someCondition ? x : y ;
   return z;
}
```

This avoids needing to check the type later

```
const something = returnTypes("blah);
something.someFunction();  // you know something has a someFunction() method.
```

Comment: The types are not the same, they might have some properties in common but I look forward to see the difference not commons.
I updated the question to clarify it better.